# Spring boot and Angular change path manually redirect to root

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am merging a Spring boot backend and an Angular frontend into one deployeable app.

When I change the path manually like `localhost/getCities/6` to `localhost/getCites/12` or refresh the page, it redirects me to root `localhost/`.

I tried to test it without backend and this way it works great. However when I build the frontend and put it to the backend I get this problem.

I don't know what else I can try and what the problem could be?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please proofread and properly format your questions. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how you configured your backend, in general the server does not know those root, somewhere in your configuration you told the server to redirect any unknown root to `localhost/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this when add this to my controller in spring boot

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class ViewController {

@RequestMapping({"/getCities/**", "/streets/**"})
   public String index() {
       return "forward:/index.html";
   }
}
```